# SVGs are displaying blurry in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari

I'm working on a site and decided to give SVGs a try. My SVGs display as they should in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. However, in Safari, the images are blurry looking. Here is what I'm doing in code:

```
<object data="section_3.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="722" class="aligncenter" >
    <img src="section_3.png" />
    <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="763" height="1602" viewBox="0 0 763 1602" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
</object>
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the images are blurry. The weird thing is when I zoom in/out in Safari, the blurriness clears up. Is there something I'm not doing in my code? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, which version of Safari are you using?

Comment: @FranciscoSalvador I was using the current version of Safari at the time. It's possible that it may have been updated since I posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your svg contains straight horizontal and vertical lines, they may seem to blur or sharpen  randomly as you zoom in and out, as they have to pick the optimum set of pixels on your screen, though that's a general browser thing, not a Safari thing.
Safari is known not to support filters or blur effects, but I don't know what's inside your svg. Your object tags make sense, and your fallback .png, but i don't understand why you then have svg tags with no content.

Comment: My SVG doesn't have blur effects, but I'm not sure about the filters; will have to double check that. As for the svg tag, if I'm using the object tag to display the svg then, do I need the svg tag at all? I'm thinking I don't since other than the blurriness in Safari, this works fine using just my object and img tags.

Comment: we tried `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` and are discussing it at https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom/issues/548 . Seems to be tough to solve. Also tried the transform solution but no luck yet.

Answer (score 9):

Adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the SVG fixed the issue for me.